# Not getting output as expected in printing star pattern in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I have tried this code and output i am getting is here

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        for($j=5-$i;$j>=1;$j--){
            echo "&nbsp;";
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }
        for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++){
            echo $i;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
     ?>
      1
     22
    333
   4444
  55555
```

but i want output like this, please tell where i am wrong

```
    1
   12
  123 
 1234
12345
```

Comment: You should post some codes.

Comment: Take this for loop: `for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++){
        echo $i;

    }` and replace the variables with some example numbers and then take a piece of paper and write down what you get every iteration.

Comment: this looks very much like homework - which you should do by yourself.

Comment: please help me in my homework, if u think that much @FranzGleichmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change echo $i to echo $k,

```
for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++){
    echo $k;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Yuva Raj it worked, one thing more if i want to print simple pyramid like pattern will the code remain the same and i have to change  only spaces please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with HTML, you may want to wrap this logic into a function that could let you choose the number of lines to display. You can tweak it to fit your needs in term of CSS :

```
function numberTriangle($endNumber, $align_text = 'right') {
    $max    = intval($endNumber);
    $align  = strval($align_text);
    $align  = ( strlen(trim($align)) > 0 ) ? $align : 'right';

    echo "<div style='text-align : $align; display : inline-block'>";

    if( $max > 0 ) {
        for( $i = 1; $i < $max + 1; $i++ ) {
            for( $j = 1; $j < $i + 1; $j++ ) {
                echo $j;
            }

            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

numberTriangle(5);

// Will display :
/*
    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
*/
```

Thanks to this function you do not have to add manual spaces anymore, which is cleaner (and saves you headhaches !).